# Python: Read HTML tables using pandas and plot using matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

So I have read an HTML table using `read_html` and stored it in a DataFrame. But when I try to plot the DF it reply with `Empty 'DataFrame' : no numeric data to plot`, I tried to convert the data type from string to float or int, but an error occur "could not convert to float".

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use('ggplot')

# read data and create a df, it will take all page tables
df = pd.read_html('https://money.cnn.com/data/us_markets/')

# Take the first read table only
df = df[0]

# Set the first column as the index
df.set_index(0, inplace=True)

df.plot()
plt.show()
```

[image: Error]

Comment: In the future please refrain from posting images of code, instead copy and paste it into the text of the question with appropriate formatting (i.e. indented by 4 spaces or surrounded by three backticks (\`\`\`))

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df = pd.read_html('https://money.cnn.com/data/us_markets')
df = df[0]

df.set_index(df.columns[0]).plot(figsize=(15,8))
```

This works.

[image]

Comment: Still got the same error, "Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot"